# Python multi-line regex greedy group

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I'm attempting to parse the following example text in Python:

```
Foo 1
foo1Text

Bar 
bar1Text

Baz 
baz1Text

Foo 2
foo2Text

Bar 
bar2Text

Baz 
baz2Text

# and so on up to Foo/Bar/Baz N
```

Now, the regex I'm using is:

```
([\S ]+)(\n*)([\s\S]*?)Bar([\s\S]*?)Baz([\s\S]*?)
```

Now - what I'd like to do is lift out the text relevant to `foo`/`bar`/`baz`. However, with the lazy qualifier on the end of the regex, `?` the expression stops short and misses the `baz2text`. Conversely, making it greedy matches everything else as part of the last group.

I'd prefer to not use a numeric qualifier if possible and broadly match things based on:

```
{title}
{stuff about title}

Bar
{stuff about Bar}

Baz
{stuff about Baz}
```

So I may iterate through each match and extract groups accordingly. Please note, I've not phrased this around extracting concrete output. I'm mostly interested in getting the regex 'groups' so they represent: `{title}`, `{stuff about title}`, `{stuff about bar}`, `{stuff about Baz}`

I was putzing around with [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fLRZwM/1) to see if I could determine the right incantation to no avail.

This is one of those problems where its easy enough to do manually. But then I wouldn't learn anything! :) I'd love to know if there's some cleaner mechanism / strategy I should be using here.

Thanks much

Comment: It's not clear what output should be.

Comment: There's not really output per-se. I'm more interested in getting the groups to lift out: {title}, {stuff about title}, {stuff about Bar}, and {stuff about Baz}. Will update the question so that's more clear.

Comment: I'm not sure where each block should stop. Please check this demo https://regex101.com/r/b8PPoL/1

Comment: I'm starting to think the same. I may have asked an impossible question. How would one distinguish between a new `{title}` and some element of multi line text from `{stuff about Baz}`? Without a discriminator, there's no way to tell. In my case, there's an implicit hierarchy that I cannot divulge here which I believe I have to use here.

Anyhow, appreciate the inputs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that `Foo` is the next group after `Baz`, then what you need is a 
[lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): `([\S ]+)(\n*)([\s\S]*?)Bar([\s\S]*?)Baz([\s\S]*?)(?=Foo)`.

Lookaheads are zero-width assertions, so it ensures a match immediately follows but doesn't change the current position.

Comment: This works with a fixed name like `Foo`, but not an arbitrary header. Though thank you for the reference to lookahead. Its a different way to look at it I did not consider. Will experiment with regexes in the lookahead expression.